# No permanent connection to the port

Tags: port, tcpclient

I've got a device to my computer and I want to read its data from port 2005

I use the following code to read from the 2005 port.

```
    public MainWindow()
  {
            try
            {

                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");

                var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

                foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
                {
                    if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(ip.ToString());
                    }
                }

                TcpClient client = null;
                try
                {
                    client = new TcpClient(localAddr.ToString(), 2005);
                }
                catch (SocketException se)
                {
                }


                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
                String data = null;

                while (true)
                {
                    data = null;

                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    int i;

                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {                       
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                        DecodeReceivedMsg(data);                       
                    }

                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {

            }
            finally
            {

            }    
 }
```

My problem is that I do not always read the port, and many times, the while(true) does not run.

please guide me

Comment: Are you getting **any** error messages or is your `while (true)` loop never executing? Unless an error has been encountered and not caught the `while(true)` will execute.

Comment: @RyanNerd : Not. I do not get error, but, except for the first time I run the program, often there is no receive data from the port. Sometimes it also receives information